# Connect Eclipse RSE with remote Linux server using public key attained from Amazon ec2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, amazon-ec2, eclipse-rse

I want a easy way to save, copy and edit files on a remote server. I'm using Eclipse as an IDE, what could be better for these tasks than RSE(Remote System Exlporer) plugin for Eclipse. The thing is that I dont know how to make a connection using a public key. I have file that I downloaded from my Amazon account, *******.pem. But I don't see any forms or inputs for this, when I try to connect to my remote Linux server. It is just User-id and password. I also tried to open the public key using the system's text editor and copy everything to my password field, but it didn't worked. Pls help me

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this was baking my noodle for a while too.  you put the keys in a folder not in the RSE config but in the whole of eclipse

check this: http://siteadmin.gforge.inria.fr/eclipse-ssh.html

Comment: It was actually quite easy. I figured out that in Preferences->General->Network Connections->SSH2 I only input the location of the public RSA key and in Preferences->General->Remote System you should set your default user-id for SSH, which in Amazon EC2 is ec2-user.

Comment: I can connect, but I only have read access. I need to edit files on /var/www and for that I need root access (at least when I'm ssh-ing into the EC2 instance).
Amazon won't allow me to connect as root, and ec2-user won't work. I have to connect as 'ubuntu'.
Any ideas on how to go around this?

Comment: The comment by @einstein should be the posted as a solution as that's the correct way of doing things. I have keys generated by PuTTYgen in My Documents. I think they are 2048 biis and work just fine. I edited the preferences to point to that directory and key. Worked just fine.

Comment: Very old thread, but seeing that this is the first hit in Google when searching for this issue. @Eric posted about logging in as root. IMO, that is always the wrong way of doing things. Instead, you should create a user id for yourself and others then either add it to sudoers.d or (the way I like doing things) add developers to a Linux group, e.g. devs and use chgrp and chmod commands to change the group of /var/www/html to dev and grant group users write access.

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned (at least in explicitly) is the fact that RSE (and for what I've seen, Eclipse in general) only seems to work with 1024 bit keys https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404714

I also had issues, because my privatekey was 2048, but I added a new key to authorized hosts and then I could connect.

Comment: My 3072 bit key generated by `ssh-keygen` did not work. Only 1024 bit key generated by Eclipse GUI worked.

Answer (score 0):

I added my local computer's `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the remote `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
Then just set the user to connect in RSE to `ec2-user` when connecting.

Someone asked for `root` login. It works too: update `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow root login:

```
#PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Then reload the sshd daemon: `service sshd restart`